# Question about electrons in electric fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I've been studying chemistry (I know this is a physics page) and I've read that electrons are supposed to lose energy because they are moving in an electric field (I know this is not actually happening).
My question would be why are they supposed to lose energy? It is because they are attracted toward the center of the atom by the positive charge of protons?

It's the coulomb force here acting as a centrifugal force, keeping the electrons in orbit? But at the same time losing energy because accelerating?

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean why an electron in Rutherford's model for an atom is supposed to lose energy?

Comment: In what context do electrons lose energy? What did you read that said that?

Comment: Yes, Rutherford's model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would an orbiting electron lose energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581151/168783)

Comment: Not really because i'm more interested in why would a moving object in an electric field lose energy.

Comment: @MarkH In the context that they are moving objects in a electric field, so they are supposed to lose energy. I don't understand why would they lose energy if they are in an electric field

Comment: Who says moving objects in electric fields are supposed to lose energy?

Comment: If an electron moves in the same direction as an electric field, it loses kinetic energy. If it moves in the opposite direction, it gains kinetic energy. This is all anyone can say unless you have a more specific situation in mind.

Comment: Doesn't it always lose energy if its always accelerating( because its in circular motion)?The centrifugal force( which I guess is caused by the electric field) keeps it in orbit.